# Can Heroku collaborators see environment variables (e.g., heroku config)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Just want to double check... if I have passwords in my environment variables, I wouldn't want any collaborator to just run `heroku config` and see those passwords.

Comment: Just curious, but what is the use case for a collaborator who does *not* have at least that level of access?  What would the collaborator who couldn't change environment variables be able to do?  For instance, if they can deploy code, they can access the env variables through code.

Comment: Well I would like a collaborator who can only deploy code because in my case I'm outsourcing bits and pieces of development when I don't have the time. That's why it's problematic.

Comment: Anyone who can deploy code can trivially access environment variables -- for instance, by adding code to print all env variables to the logs at runtime.  If you are outsourcing development, either trust your dev resources to handle your passwords, or don't let them deploy... and review code they produce *very* thoroughly.  Ultimately, being able to add code to your application without review is more power than being able to see your passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku collaborators can indeed see your environment variables (and change them!).  The short list of things collaborators cannot do include adding paid features to the account and changing ownership or billing information.